# Can't pass a string to get the value of "description" in OpenWeatherMap API JSON

Tags: android, json, api, android-studio, kotlin

This is the [API](https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=tehran&appid=271ea148dac251e8c09580f4d1119bed&lang=fa&&units=metric)

[Check this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rui8v.png)

I want to get the value of "description" but I can't pass a string.

Comment: Please post your code inline rather than as a link to an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `weatherObject` is a `jsonArray` so can only be accessed by index (i.e. Int).  You probably meant to instantiate your weatherObject as a `jsonObject`:

```
val weatherObject = weatherArray.getJSONObject(0)
```